# Processing Class/object variable stacking

Tags: class, object, stack, processing, distortion

So I have a problem that I've managed to fix before (by fluke) in simpler programs, but still don't know what the actual problem is.

I have created an class containing the following variables `g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 37, 10, 20,160, 0);`. The problem is, when I run one object of the class it's all fine and a nice graph is created. Though when I run two objects of the class, the first graph in the program runs fine and the second one gets morphed out of proportion. Almost like variables are stacking or multiplying each other.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

The Main sketch's code:

```
Graph g1 = new Graph();
Button b1 = new Button();

TableRow hrMeasure;
TableRow spoMeasure;
TableRow tempMeasure;

Table tableHr;
Table tableSpo;
Table tableAbp;
Table tableResp;
Table tableTemp;

int i;
int border;
float p;

PFont font;
PFont font2;
String alarmColor;


void setup(){
  font = loadFont("data/OpenSans-36.vlw");
  textFont(font,36);

  frameRate(15);
  smooth(8);
  size(1024,768);

  tableHr = loadTable("testfile.csv", "header");
  tableSpo = loadTable("testfile2.csv", "header");
  tableAbp = loadTable("testfile3.csv", "header");
  tableResp = loadTable("testfile4.csv", "header");
  tableTemp = loadTable("testfile5.csv", "header");

}

void draw(){

  retrieveData();
  GUI();
  relativeGraph();
  buttons();

    g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 40, 15, 25,200,100);
 // g1.display(tableSpo, spoMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,2);
 // g1.display(tableTemp, tempMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,3);
 // g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 37, 13, 18,160,4);
 // g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 37, 13, 18,160,5);
}

//retrieving data from the csv file
void retrieveData(){
  i++;
  hrMeasure = tableHr.getRow(i);
  spoMeasure = tableSpo.getRow(i);
  tempMeasure = tableTemp.getRow(i);  
}
```

Class:

```
class Graph {
int adjustment;
float p;
int greenRelative, yellowRelative, redRelative;
float[] measure = new float[1500000];
String alarmColor;
int timer, counter;
int greenTimer, yellowTimer, redTimer;
int graphHeight = 80;
int graphLength = 800;

void display(Table table, TableRow measurement, int average, int bound1, int bound2,int x, int y){

p = measurement.getFloat("value");

pushMatrix();
translate(width,0);
scale(-1,1);

for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){

  adjustment = width-table.getRowCount()-x; // adjustment to the x-coordinate, so every graph will start at 0

//if statement for green readings
   if(measure[i]  > average-bound1 && measure[i] < average+bound1){    
   stroke(0, 255, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);  
   alarmColor = "green";
 }else{

//if statement for yellow readings
   if(measure[i]  <= average-bound1 && measure[i] > average-bound2|| measure[i]  >= average+bound1 && measure[i] < average+bound2){
   stroke(255, 255, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);

   alarmColor = "yellow";

//else red
 }else{stroke(255, 0, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);

   alarmColor = "red";
 }}
line(i+adjustment, graphHeight-map(measure[i], average-bound1-bound2, 37, 0,graphHeight/2)+y, (i+1)+adjustment, graphHeight-map(measure[i+1], average-bound1-bound2, 37, 0,graphHeight/2)+y); 
}
popMatrix();

for(int i=0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
measure[i] = measure[i+1];
measure[i+1] = p;
println(measure[i]);
}
```

Comment: The main sketch using the graphs isn't visible, therefore it's hard to tell if the issue relates to how the graphs are drawn (and coordinate system transformations) or the data used (e.g. does each Graph have a separate Table instance ? etc.)

Comment: I'll post the main sketch

Comment: In the current code  can see a single graph instance.

Comment: True, I closed off the other graphs (//), if you remove those you can see what the problem is.

Comment: Without a bit of data, I won't be able to test 1:1, but have you tried using two independent Graph instances ? (e.g. ```Graph g2 = new Graph();``` at the top, then ```g1.display(tableSpo, spoMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,2);``` in ```draw()``` ? (Also make sure the position don't allow overlayed content)

Comment: Ofcourse! I was using the same g1 instance for both graphs, this is why the data was being morphed. Switching to a g1 and g2 graph solved the problem.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an expanded answer bellow so it's easier for others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are using independent instances, for example:

```
Graph g1 = new Graph();
Graph g2 = new Graph();
```

then in `draw()`:

```
g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 40, 15, 25,200,100);
g2.display(tableSpo, spoMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,2);
```

Full listing:

```
Graph g1 = new Graph();
Graph g2 = new Graph();
Graph g3 = new Graph();
Graph g4 = new Graph();
Graph g5 = new Graph();
Button b1 = new Button();

TableRow hrMeasure;
TableRow spoMeasure;
TableRow tempMeasure;

Table tableHr;
Table tableSpo;
Table tableAbp;
Table tableResp;
Table tableTemp;

int i;
int border;
float p;

PFont font;
PFont font2;
String alarmColor;


void setup(){
  font = loadFont("data/OpenSans-36.vlw");
  textFont(font,36);

  frameRate(15);
  smooth(8);
  size(1024,768);

  tableHr = loadTable("testfile.csv", "header");
  tableSpo = loadTable("testfile2.csv", "header");
  tableAbp = loadTable("testfile3.csv", "header");
  tableResp = loadTable("testfile4.csv", "header");
  tableTemp = loadTable("testfile5.csv", "header");

}

void draw(){

  retrieveData();
  GUI();
  relativeGraph();
  buttons();

    g1.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 40, 15, 25,200,100);
    g2.display(tableSpo, spoMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,2);
    g3.display(tableTemp, tempMeasure, 37, 1, 3,160,3);
    g4.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 37, 13, 18,160,4);
    g5.display(tableHr, hrMeasure, 37, 13, 18,160,5);
}

//retrieving data from the csv file
void retrieveData(){
  i++;
  hrMeasure = tableHr.getRow(i);
  spoMeasure = tableSpo.getRow(i);
  tempMeasure = tableTemp.getRow(i);  
}

class Graph {
int adjustment;
float p;
int greenRelative, yellowRelative, redRelative;
float[] measure = new float[1500000];
String alarmColor;
int timer, counter;
int greenTimer, yellowTimer, redTimer;
int graphHeight = 80;
int graphLength = 800;

void display(Table table, TableRow measurement, int average, int bound1, int bound2,int x, int y){

p = measurement.getFloat("value");

pushMatrix();
translate(width,0);
scale(-1,1);

for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){

  adjustment = width-table.getRowCount()-x; // adjustment to the x-coordinate, so every graph will start at 0

//if statement for green readings
   if(measure[i]  > average-bound1 && measure[i] < average+bound1){    
   stroke(0, 255, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);  
   alarmColor = "green";
 }else{

//if statement for yellow readings
   if(measure[i]  <= average-bound1 && measure[i] > average-bound2|| measure[i]  >= average+bound1 && measure[i] < average+bound2){
   stroke(255, 255, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);

   alarmColor = "yellow";

//else red
 }else{stroke(255, 0, 0);
   strokeWeight(1);

   alarmColor = "red";
 }}
line(i+adjustment, graphHeight-map(measure[i], average-bound1-bound2, 37, 0,graphHeight/2)+y, (i+1)+adjustment, graphHeight-map(measure[i+1], average-bound1-bound2, 37, 0,graphHeight/2)+y); 
}
popMatrix();

for(int i=0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
measure[i] = measure[i+1];
measure[i+1] = p;
println(measure[i]);
}
```

Comment: One more follow up question: Is it also possible to make an array of moving objects? When I try to make an array, it seems the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you please post a separate question so I can see how you've attempted to implement the array version ?

Comment: Sure, I'll post the link in a few minutes.